# Proof concerning Fibonacci and recursively defined sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing, fibonacci-numbers, recursion

> The series $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is given through 
>   $$a_1=1,\quad a_2=\frac{1}{2},\quad a_{n+2}=a_na_{n+1} \quad\text{ for } n\geq1.$$
>   I want to show that $$a_n = 2^{-f_{n-1}}$$ whereas $\,f_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number.

I did a proof with induction, but now I came up with this. Out of the initial figures, the definition of $f_n$, and the exponent and logarithm rules I think it is

\begin{align}
     &\quad  a_{n} = 2^{\,\log_2 a_n} = 2^{\,\log_2 (a_{n-2} \,\cdot\, a_{n-1})}\\
 \Longleftrightarrow  &\quad  a_n = 2^{\,\log_2 (a_{n-2}) \,+\, \log_2 (a_{n-1})}\\
 \Longleftrightarrow  &\quad  \log_2 a_n = \log_2 2^{\,\log_2 (a_{n-2}) \,+\, \log_2 (a_{n-1})}\\
 \Longleftrightarrow  &\quad  \log_2 a_n = \log_2 a_{n-2} \,+\, \log_2 a_{n-1}\\
 \Longleftrightarrow  &\quad  (-\log_2 a_n) = (-\log_2 a_{n-2}) + (-\log_2 a_{n-1}) \quad(*)
\end{align}

and with the initial figures $-\log_2 a_1 = 0$ and $-\log_2 a_2 = 1$ the negative expononents form the Fibonacci sequence $2^{-f_{n-1}}$ with $(*)$.

### Is that valid? Thanks!

Comment: I think the proof is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should at least mention that $a_n\gt 0$ for every $n$.

Note that taking the logarithm of $a_{n+2}=a_na_{n+1}$ directly is simpler :
$$\log_2 a_{n+2}=\log_2 a_n+\log_2 a_{n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is fine. However, I'd suggest another version. Initialization: $a_1 = 2^{-f_0}$ (assuming $f_0  =0$), $a_2 = 2^{-f_1}$ (assuming $f_0  =1$). It happens that $a_3 = a_1*a_2 = 2^{-f_0-f_1} = 2^{-f_2}$ . Now suppose the property is valid up to index $k\ge 2$. Then $a_{k+1} = a_{k}a_{k-1} = 2^{-f_{k-1}}2^{-f_{k-2}} = 2^{-f_{k-1}-f_{k-2}}  = 2^{-f_{k}}$. So it is valid for index $k+1$ as well.

Thus, you do not have to play with $\log$s, which requires positivity.